# VS Code error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'execCode')" when trying to run python file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run a `.py` file using VS Code. But whenever I try to run a file, I get a pop up which reads `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'execCode')`.

Now I do not know what the problem is and do not have enough experience to troubleshoot the problem. A google search does not bring up anything useful.

I am running `python 3.9.15` on hte newest version of VS Code on a Windows 11 machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed python extension?

You can search in the extension store.

[image]

You can also read [VsCode document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) for more details.

Comment: Hey there. Yes I have including a few other extensions as well.

Comment: Can simple `print ("HelloWorld")` run? Can you paste your code into the article?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a new environment on your console, either virtual or with Anaconda.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34042571)